# Objective-C. I have typedef float DuglaType[3]. How do I declare the property for this?

Tags: objective-c, properties, typedef

I have:

```
typedef float DuglaType[3];
   @interface Foo : NSObject {  
   DuglaType _duglaType;  
}
```

How do I correctly declare the property?

I tried:

```
// .h  
@property DuglaType duglaType;

// .m  
@synthesize duglaType = _duglaType;
```

But this spews errors.

What is the secret handshake for C++ typedefs to play nice with Obj-C properties? Thanks.

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: The problem is that you can't return an array from a method.

Comment: Yah, I finally realized that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My work around is to bail on using @property and implement setter/getters:

// .h

- (float *) duglaType;
- (void) setDuglaType: (DuglaType)input;

// .m

- (float *) duglaType {

  return &_duglaType[0];

}

- (void) setDuglaType: (DuglaType)input {

  m3dCopyMatrix44f(_duglaType, input);

}

I guess typdef-ing an array give Obj-C headaches. No worries.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

Typedef the array into a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    float p[3];
} DuglaType;


- (DuglaType) duglaType
{
    return _duglaType;
}

- (void) setDuglaType:(DuglaType) input
{
    m3dCopyMatrix44f(&_duglaType.p[0], &input.p[0]); 
}
```